# fasttext produces a different vector after training

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, nlp, fasttext

Here's my training:

```
import fasttext

model = fasttext.train_unsupervised('data.txt', model='skipgram')
```

Now, let's observe the first vector (omitted the full output for readability)

```
model.get_input_vector(0)

# array([-0.1988439 ,  0.40966552,  0.47418243,  0.148709  ,  0.5891477
```

On the other hand, let's input the first string into our model:

```
model[data.iloc[0]]

# array([ 0.10782535,  0.3055557 ,  0.19097836, -0.15849613, 0.14204402
```

We get a different vector.

Why?

Answer (score 1):

You should have explained more about `data` structure. By the way, when you are using `model[data.iloc[0]]`, it is equivalent to `model.get_word_vector(data.iloc[0])`. So, you should pass a word to the model.

On the other hand, `model.get_input_vector(0)` might input a sentence to the model. Therefore, you can compare the result of `model.get_input_vector(0)` with `model.get_sentence_vector(data.iloc[0])`, if `data.iloc[0]` is a sentence. Otherwise, you should get the first word in the data to input to the `model` and then compare their vectors.

Comment: Yes, `data.iloc[0]` is indeed a sentence. I made the comparison as explained in your answer but oddly, still getting different vectors

Comment: @Elimination Do you mean pass the first word of the `data.iloc[0]` to the `model`? Keep in mind that you can pass `data.iloc[0]` to `model.get_sentence_vector` and then compare the results.

Comment: No, I want to pass the whole sentence. Here's my comparison.   

(1) `model.get_sentence_vector(data.iloc[0])` 
(2) `model.get_input_vector(0)`. Why are they different?

Comment: To better understand the problem, you should post a sample of your data. In any case, are you sure that the first input vector is the same that your first row of data?

Comment: @Elimination Please let us know the vector of the first word of `data.iloc[0]` by `model.get_word_vector`.